# Why is it better to use case in function args for pattern matching in a map function

Tags: scala

The Scala [cheatsheet](http://docs.scala-lang.org/cheatsheets/) say to "use case in function args for pattern matching." as such

```
GOOD (xs zip ys) map { case (x,y) => x*y }
BAD (xs zip ys) map( (x,y) => x*y )
```

Why is the former better?

Answer (score 5):

`(x, y) => x * y` is syntactic sugar for the following (I'll assume we're talking about integers):

```
new Function2[Int, Int, Int] {
  def apply(x: Int, y: Int): Int = x * y
}
```

`map` on collections takes a `A => B` (which desugars to `Function1[A, B]`), which is a completely different type from `Function2`. So one good reason not to use the latter version in your example is that the compiler won't accept it.

In cases where you have a method that actually takes a `Function2`, you can use either:

```
scala> val pair = (List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5, 6))
pair: (List[Int], List[Int]) = (List(1, 2, 3),List(4, 5, 6))

scala> pair.zipped.map { (x, y) => x * y }
res0: List[Int] = List(4, 10, 18)

scala> pair.zipped.map { case (x, y) => x * y }
res1: List[Int] = List(4, 10, 18)
```

The `case` version works because of how the compiler supports pattern matching in the function literal syntax for `Function2`. In general I'd personally prefer the `(x, y) => x * y` syntax *when it works* (i.e., when your method expects a `Function2` and you don't need to do any other pattern matching).

Comment: Do you know why `pair.zipped` and `(pair._1 zip pair._2)` work differently?

Comment: `pair.zipped` is designed to support optimization—it doesn't require the construction of a bunch of tuples that are just going to be thrown away immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the latter simply won't work.

```
scala> val xs = List(1, 2, 3)
xs: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> val ys = List(4, 5, 6)
ys: List[Int] = List(4, 5, 6)

scala> (xs zip ys).map((x,y) => x*y)
<console>:10: error: missing parameter type
Note: The expected type requires a one-argument function accepting a 2-Tuple.
      Consider a pattern matching anonymous function, `{ case (x, y) =>  ... }`
              (xs zip ys).map((x,y) => x*y)
                               ^
<console>:10: error: missing parameter type
              (xs zip ys).map((x,y) => x*y)
                                 ^

scala> (xs zip ys).map { case (x,y) => x*y }
res0: List[Int] = List(4, 10, 18)
```

As an alternative

```
import Function.tupled
(xs zip ys) map tupled { (x,y) => x*y }
```

Answer (score -1):

With pattern matching, you are explicitly specifying the form (type) of the input parameter to map (a one-argument function accepting a tuple-2); in the second case (without pattern matching), you would need to explicitly specify the type (as it has the same form as a 2-argument function).  You can see this by just typing it into the REPL (scala 2.11.6):

```
scala> val xs = List(1,2,3,4)
xs: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
scala> val ys = List(1,2,3,4)
ys: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
scala> (xs zip ys) map { case (x,y) => x*y }
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 4, 9, 16)
scala> (xs zip ys) map ((x,y) => x*y)
<console>:10: error: missing parameter type
Note: The expected type requires a one-argument function accepting
a 2-Tuple.
Consider a pattern matching anonymous function, `{ case (x, y) =>  }`
          (xs zip ys) map ((x,y) => x*y)
                            ^
<console>:10: error: missing parameter type
          (xs zip ys) map ((x,y) => x*y)
```